# Can anyone provide me the English transliteration of the famous hymn sung by Lord Indra to Mother Lakshmi in the Vishnu Purana?

Tags: indra, lakshmi, vishnu-purana

There is a famous hymn sung by Lord Indra to Mother Lakshmi in the Vishnu Purana (Book 1, Chapter 9) after the Devas had regained immortality. Could anyone provide me the English <s>translation</s> **transliteration** of the hymn?

Comment: @Pandya I know. I am asking for the English transliteration of that hymn, not the English translation.

Comment: @surya kanta bose chowdhury I am sorry for that I got confused between translation and transliteration,my bad):

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda It's my fault. I wrote "transliteration" in the header and "translation" in the body.

Comment: Transliteration is also off-topic.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, I know, that's why I close voters it yesterday while reviewing my past questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English Transliteration of Lakshmi Stotra sung by Indra in Vishnu Puranam Book 1, Chapter 9, is thus-

[**Lakshmi Stotra in English Transliteration**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/mahaalaxmiistotra.html?lang=en-IN)

And ITX - [**Lakshmi Stotras**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/mahaalaxmiistotra.itx)

Comment: You can also get [itx](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/mahaalaxmiistotra.itx).